# Weak/No shadows? ( EEVEE )

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

Ive created a shadow catcher to suit an HDRI image. The shadow catcher is only basically doing ambient occlusion and there is no signs of shadows. There should be an entire shadow under the car.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the material nodes of the shadow catcher? Or a .blend? Also, shadow catchers in eevee are only a hacky way to do proper shadow catchers, I'd suggest looking more into the topic, there are some good tutorials on youtube.

Comment: I've edited the post with the shadow catcher node.

Answer (score 0):

Try this setup:
[image]
I only changed the diffuse color and the white handle on the color ramp. I also had a downwards facing sun lamp. Which, mind you, will ruin the shadow catcher if you rotate it beyond a certain point, you can play around with that and try to compensate those two values I changed to your own scene.